# Check presence of database in windows mobile 6.1

Tags: c#

How to check whether a particular database is present in windows mobile 6.0 C# code 
or 
how to get all .sdf file from windows mobile 6.0 application

Answer (score 0):

`if (!File.Exists(@"Program Files\ApplicationFolder\DatabseName.sdf"))

{
//enter your code..
 }`

Comment: this will check whether DatabseName.sdf is present